# Equal widths / heights with parent (root) view?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to add constraint in Storyboard to an UIImageView to it's superview, equal widths or heights but it's disabled.

I tried selecting both the view and the superview, then the add constraints button at the bottom right (mentioned constraints appear disabled), I tried dragging from view to the superview (mentioned constraints aren't listed).

I tried removing all the constrants related to my view. Didn't make a difference.

I'm using a xib, of a custom view. The parent view is also the root view. XCode 6.2 beta. Using size class Any/Any.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: You can do it. How are you trying to add constraints? Via Ctrl+Click+Drag or via pin panel at the bottom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For making UIView height/Width equals to super View. 
Here's what you need to do.

You can set leading,top,tailing and bottom constraint by right clicking to View and select superview.
 [image]
After setting Top and bottom constraints as i've set in previous image. You need to update constraints to '0' as it might have top and leading space not equal to '0'. You can select those constraints and changes constant to '0'.
[image]
You can also set constraints from pin to View as i've set for leading and tailing you can also set top and bottom option in similar way.
[image]

EDIT:
If you want to set width and height equally then you need to select both the view and set it's equal height and equal width. As I've set them in below image.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Result:
[image]
Below two images shows how you can changes width/ height using multiplier as you need to set constant to 0.9. as from storyboard or xib you cannot set constant in float. So you need to set multiplier.

First Image I've set multiplier in ratio.
[image]

Second Image I've set multiplier to 0.9
[image]

If you still face any queries please let me know. Hope this will help you solve your problem.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I'm asking specifically for equal width/height constraints, which is different than spacing constraints. The reason I need that is because I want to make the view proportional to the superview, e.g. set a constant 0.9.

Comment: Answer does not provide a solution to the specific equal widths/heights question so is incorrect in stating that it "that "making UIView height/Width equals to super View". Rather, it is based on a workaround using leading/trailing gaps. If multiples are required for proportion, it won't do the business.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod as per his question he required to give equal width/height constraints. And to set view to proportional you need to use multiplier. By using multiplier set to 1/2 with equal width you can set view in centre and make it half the width of superview. But for that you also need to give centre horizontally and vertically to view/image view and also give equal height and width and set 0.9 in multiplier.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't give the inner view (UIImageview) any width or height
- Add top margin (with superview) with 0
- Add bottom margin (with superview) with 0
- Add left margin (with superview) with -16
- Add right margin (with superview) with -16

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended adding a parent view in between. This parent is constained to the top view - left, right, top, bottom: 0, and then I can set my inner view to equals width and hight to the parent (the reason I want to do that is to make proportional size - set constant to e.g. 0.9).

No idea why it's not possible to do this directly with the root view.